# Xamarin forms Imagesource not working on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So I am working on a project and want to get an image from my server to the application.
I use an imagesource to get the image I need and it works fine on UWP but when I test it on Android it does not work. I tried everything I could find on the internet and it is still not working.

If you could help that would be great,
Thank you.

```
ImageSource fotoopad = ImageSource.FromFile("uploadplaceholder.png");
if (x.FotoPath != "") fotoopad = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(XamerinAPP.LoginApp.apiUrl + @"/api/media/image/" + x.Id));
```

and the xamarin.

```
<Image x:Name="StackMediaIMAGE" IsVisible="{Binding isFoto}" Source="{Binding fotoPad}"/>
```

Comment: This is not sufficient information or code to effectively help you. "I tried everything I could find...", what does that mean, what have you tried? When you debug your app on Android, what's the value for `x.FotoPath`? Where does that even come from?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is **Not Reproducible or Caused by a typo**. Based on the self answer by the OP - "*I made a mistake on the server that it would get an image with "api/getimagebyid/4/" while it should be "api/getimagebyid/4"*"

Answer (score 0):

What's the code of the bind property `fotoPad` for the Image?

In general, if we want to bind a property to an image, we can do as follows:

1.add a property `fotoPad` in the viewModel of current page.

for example:

```
public class Item
{       
    public string fotoPad { get; set; } 

    public bool isFoto{ get; set; }
}
```

2.and a correct format of `fotoPad` is as follows:

```
new Item
        {  
            isFoto = true,
            fotoPad = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Alouatta_guariba.jpg/200px-Alouatta_guariba.jpg"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Xamarin for Android try getting the Uri the following way:

```
Android.Net.Uri photoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"{ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource}://{PackageName}/{<YourPackageName>.Droid.Resource.Raw.<YourPngFileName>}");
```

Replace < YourPackageName > and < YourPngFileName > for the concrete data in your project.

Save the image.png (for example) under Resources/raw folder in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake on the server that it would get an image with "api/getimagebyid/4/" while it should be "api/getimagebyid/4" and that made it not work for some reason on Android. After fixing that mistake it worked.